# Flash AS3 How to i change a value of a textbox inside a button?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, textfield

Hello and thanks for taking time helping me :)

I have a button named "bt_buy_1" and inside it i have a textfield named "price_1" and i want to change the value of the textfield "price_1" so it raise by 50 each time u click it but not that my real problem... my real problem is that i dont know how to change a textbox when its inside a button... i can do it with a symbol (MovieClip) but with a button i cant... :(

so do any one know how to change the textfiled inside a button?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote:

> i can do it with a symbol (MovieClip) but with a button i cant...

Since you know how to change text inside an MC why not do it that way? If the problem is having something "clickable" then you must know that actually MCs can be clickable too just like buttons (also can listen out for pointer rollovers, button press/release etc etc)

Anyways to make your MC behave like a button here is some quick example code to test.

```
var cashCount:Number = 0; 

button_MC.buttonMode = true;
button_MC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaseCash);

function increaseCash (e:MouseEvent):void
{
 cashCount += 50; //increments up by 50 when MC is clicked
 button_MC.cashAmount.text = String(cashCount);
 trace("Clicked for Cash.. amount is now: " + cashCount);
}
```

Note: **cashAmount** is the textbox instance name, **button_MC** is the instance name of the MovieClip you want clickable. Also "embed font" on your text if there's a problem displaying the numbers adding up (it happens sometimes, y'know). Peace out.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) but do you know how to remove the cursur icon when you hold over the text i only want the curser icon like when its a button? ^^

Comment: Dunno if you solved it already but there's two possible ways. First you can use `button_MC.useHandCursor = false;` or you can try `button_MC.buttonMode = false;` either way the MC will still respond to a click event if you keep the  `MC_name.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, etc)` code.  **TIP** Never have just text in your MC button as you will have to click the letters precisely (the hole in "O" is not a clickable button area) to fix that put in a layer underneath text layer with some shape defining clickable area (i.e box) then give that a zero alpha in Properties-->Colour Settings. Bam

Comment: PS: btw Flash doesn't allow hand cursor over textfields (even inside a button MC) since users may need that right-click & copy text option. Try moving your mouse to the actual text/numbers and you will see the hand cursor disappears within textfield area. I get what you meant though and the previos comment works ok.